# Accessing entries in a matrix field in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, entries-field

I am writing a plugin function that takes an entry id, the entry has a matrix field (called block) and the matrix has a blocktype which contains a number field (blockStep), an entries field (blockContent) and another entries field (blockDependency).

I am getting the entry, which i am calling a module, like this:

```
$module = craft()->entries->getEntryById($moduleid);
```

This works fine. Then I get the matrix field, called block, like this:

```
$matrixBlocks = $module->block;
```

This also works fine. However, when I try to loop through the matrix field, like this:

```
    foreach ($matrixBlocks as $block){
      var_dump( $block->getContent()->blockStep);
      var_dump( $block->getContent()->blockContent);
      var_dump( $block->getContent()->blockDependency);
    }
```

Only the blockStep, which is a number, is set - the two entries fields are just returning `NULL`.

Can someone help? How should I be accessing these entries fields?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the Craft docs cover this quite nicely? https://craftcms.com/docs/matrix-fields#templating

Comment: Those docs cover templating, this is in plugin development. Can you tell me how to do it in a plugin? I have obviously checked the docs, but I cant find how to do it.

Comment: Ow my bad, completely overlooked that part... let me see if I can dig something up

Answer (score 2):

I think I've figured out how to do this now (mainly through trial and error).
The code above should actually be like this:

```
foreach ($matrixBlocks as $block) {

    foreach ($block->blockContent as $blockContent) {
        ....
    }
    foreach ($block->blockDependency as $blockDependency){
        ....
    }
}
```

And the the `$blockContent` and `$blockDependency` variables will contain the entries required.